# $L^{2}$ functions.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $L^{2}(I)$ be the set of $L^2$ functions, $f : I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values on $L^{2}(I)$ and let $f_{0}\in L^{2}(I)$ be a function such that

\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}\left[\cfrac{X(s) - f_{0}(s)}{|X(s) - f_{0}(s)|}\right] = 0,
\end{equation}
for all $s\in I$. If we denote by $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$ the $L^{2}$ norm, my question is whether or not

\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}\left[\cfrac{X - f_{0}}{\|X - f_{0}\|_{L^2}}\right](s) = \text{E}\left[\cfrac{X(s) - f_{0}(s)}{|X(s) - f_{0}(s)|}\right],
\end{equation}
for all $s\in I$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: The functional $B : L^{2}(I)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $B(f) = f(s)$ for $s\in I$ is linear. If $B$ is bounded, you can evaluate the interior of the expectation. But the $L^{2}$ norm in the denominator is a problem.